# How to get the Joins right in a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, as follows:

**People**:

```
First_Name Last_Name
  Bill       Smith
  David      Williams
  Fred       Jones
  Freda      Jones
  Jane       Smith
  John       Smith
  Peter      Williams
  Sally      Williams
```

**Pets**:

```
Species Title  Owner
  Dog    Fido   Jones
  Cat    Tibs   Jones
  Dog    Jock   Williams
```

I know it's a weird database design, but please don't tell me to redesign the database. It's an example that represents the real problem, which is more complicated and can't be redesigned.

I am trying to formulate a query that will return exactly one row for each person, and a column containing the title of their Cat or null if they do not own a cat (I used `Title` because `Name` is a reserved word and Access complained).

The nearest I have come up with is:

```
SELECT People.*, Pets.Title
FROM People 
LEFT JOIN Pets ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner
WHERE Pets.Species IS NULL OR Pets.Species = "Cat"
```

However this doesn't list any rows for the Williams family because they own a dog.

I have tagged this as MS Access because I am actually using Access 97 (don't ask!), but, other than Access's rather limited Join facilities, it should be a general SQL question.

Comment: You may have a problem if (in the full schema) you only have a last name (partial key) to identify the owner of the cat.  You could have people living in different houses both with the last name of Williams.  According to your schema, all their pets are jointly owned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: The left join syntax in Access causes trouble, which means that for access we need to involve a subquery. This will look something like (the untested);

```
SELECT People.*, Pets.Title
FROM People LEFT JOIN 
  [SELECT Pets.* FROM Pets WHERE Pets.Species = 'Cat']. AS Pets 
    ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner
```

-- Original answer --

What you seem to want is a regular left join with an additional condition that the pet needs to be a cat;

```
SELECT People.*, Pets.Title
FROM People LEFT JOIN Pets 
  ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner AND Pets.Species = 'Cat'
```

The reason for *not* putting the cat condition in a `WHERE` clause is that a where clause eliminates all non matches, while putting it in the `ON` clause makes the result NULL if it can't find a match (just as you describe your desired result)

Comment: I tried exactly that, but I just get "Join expression not supported". Apparently that is not legal in an ON clause.

Comment: @Dave Doh, Access syntax vs SQL Syntax gets me every time :) Updated the answer.

Comment: You got there about the same time as I did, see below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> this doesn't list any rows for the Williams family because they own a Dog

That's because of the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE Pets.Species IS NULL OR Pets.Species = "Cat"
```

If `Pets.Species` is `"Dog"` then this would evaluate to false, so those records are not shown.  First remove the clause entirely:

```
SELECT People.*, Pets.Title
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Pets ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner
```

Now you're getting the *records* you want, but not specifically the *data* you want.  The `Title` column is showing any value, and you only want it to show `"Cat"` or `NULL`.  You can adjust the `JOIN` to achieve that:

```
SELECT People.*, Pets.Title
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Pets ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner
              AND Pets.Species = 'Cat'
```

This will filter the *joined* table, but not the entire result set.

Comment: David, I tried this, see comment above. Perhaps this is a weakness of Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT People.*, case when Pets.Species = 'Cat' then Pets.Title else null end as Title
 FROM People LEFT JOIN Pets ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner
```

Comment: This is a nice idea. Access doesn't support Case, but I did manage an equivalent using IIF:

SELECT People.*, IIF(Pets.Species = 'Cat', Pets.Title, NULL) as Title, Species
FROM People LEFT JOIN Pets ON People.Last_Name = Pets.Owner

Unfortunately it leaves extra rows (for Fred and Freda Jones, who also have a dog) which I can't get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - I finally got it:

```
SELECT People.*, Pets.Title FROM 
People LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Pets WHERE Species='Cat') AS PeopleWithCats 
ON People.Last_Name=PeopleWithCats.Owner
```